# Writing to and Reading From a csv file (Java)

Tags: csv, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I tried to read from a csv file (data.csv) and write what I read to another csv file (dataNew.csv). Then I added just one entry to dataNew. All the entries were copied successfully and the entry I added additionally can also be seen in dataNew.csv. I then tried to bring all the entries to the console. However only 74 of 101 lines were printed out. I want to figure out why.

```java
public class StudentDataTestExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("./src/data.csv");
        File file2 = new File("./src/dataNew.csv");
        String line = null;
        String line2 = null;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
             BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                bw.write(line + "\n");


            String s = String.format("%d;%s;%s;%s;%s", 123442,"ece", "erkul", "erkulece@gmail.com","mathe 1, mathe 2, BuK, Anwendungssysteme, Konstruktion 3");
            bw.write(s);

            while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(br2.readLine());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Could it be because you don't close your buffered writer before attempting to read the file?

Comment: I added the br.close() command before the second while loop. Now it prints out all the entries I copied. Thank you.                                                               However, I still cannot see the entry I added additionally on the console, although I closed the writer after all the write commands and before the second loop. Why would that be ?

Comment: That's bc i did not add it as an object. I got it, thanks.